# Find methods and params in files using regular expression

Tags: regex

So i am trying to search php files using `preg_match_all` to find method usages in there and take parameter values from it.

For example if i there is method call like:

`method("some text", null, "third param")`

I want to get `some text`, `null`, and `third param` to an array.

I was able to get first parameter, bug having problems for second and third one.

What i tryed:

`\(method)\([\'"](.*?[ \na-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[\'"]\im`

https://regex101.com/r/dC8wV6/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
method\s*\(((?:\s*(?:['"][^'"]*['"]|\w+)\s*(?:,|(?=\))))*)
```

to capture the parameters in group 1, then split them on `,` or `,(?=(?:(?:[^'"]*['"]){2})*[^'"]*$)` to get an array of parameters.

This pattern comes with the usual pitfalls, i.e. commas in strings (`method(" , ")`) or mismatched quotes (`" ' "`) or escaped quotes (`" \" "`) will trip it up. Those issues could be fixed, but I think the regex is long enough as is.